# Can the battery indicator(status area) of Android changed to something like this?

Tags: usability, gui-design

The previous versions of android had the battery indicator as a dynamic illustration along with a provision to view the battery in percentage in the status area of the phone.

Also in lollipop, we have to swipe down twice to see the battery percentage.

**Android (till KitKat)**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuG4eJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Wouldn't it be much better if they come up with a design which provides both battery icon and the percentage as a single icon,

**My Design:**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSttU.png)</sup>

there by ***saving the space of one icon*** in the already crowded status area?

Also the bottom rectangle can illustrate the health of the battery using different colors.

Also plugged status can be provided like the the lightning symbol behind the charge percentage. [I couldn't create that mock-up of that in the online editor :) ]

**EDIT:**
For few who feel that it will take more space, I suggest we either use slim font or remove the percentage symbol like,

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6OWq1.png)</sup>

Comment: That looks close to one of the styles available in Cyanogenmod (select "icon portrait" and check "show battery status percent") except it uses a varying degree of fill and just two colours (default or red) along with the text.

Comment: @JonHanna Haven't used Cyanogenmod to be frank. So no idea

Comment: You should take a look. I prefer its circle icon myself though; while not looking like a dry cell doesn't say "battery" as immediately, it's got good clarity-for-space value.

Comment: That I've seen. Available with some apps in playstore as well. But the dry cell icon adds the value to the UX similar to the floppy icon for save which we use. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It does, which is why I mentioned not having it as a down-side. That said, my phone is in my pocket and I look at it regularly (no need to wonder "what does that symbol mean" any more), and the circle is still reasonably guessable anyway. On balance, I prefer it. Still, there is also two dry-cell like icons available (landscape and portrait) that do indeed overlay percentage text on the icon.

Comment: I suppose some people like to look at their battery icon to quickly evaluate their battery life instead of reading (which isn't that much slower). I only have the battery text, without the icon ( CM11S).

Comment: @VinceCgto Devs like us will prefer the text. Think of the average users who constitute the maximum users :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my personal preference it's sometimes (*or most of the time*) convenient to just get an idea of battery status by having a look of filled or empty status of battery indicator (Like the one with default battery indicator ).

Though, I am supportive to your idea of saving the space and moving the `%` inside battery icon but then we will have to take care of few points:

- Making the default battery icon little big ( big enough to hold the
  1-100% at legible font )
- If we are to go with the coloured indicator
  like the one you have suggested (*Red for Low, Green for Full etc.*
  ) then we will have to vary the `%` color accordingly to make the `%`
  readable with varying battery indicator colors.

Comment: I think we can go for slim font or even cut the "%" symbol

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard yeah cutting the `%` can be an option

Comment: So we are only away from calling Google :)

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard haha yeah I suppose so... make it happen dude :)

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard Additionally, to avoid the extra character, change what would be 100 to a tick sign or something similar.

Comment: Yeah was thinking of letter "F"  but a tick will be more good

Comment: @Prinsig yeah that would be great

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an icon like that that would still fit into the notification area it would mean the text of your proposed icon would have to be even smaller than it currently is, this would make it incredibly difficult for those with poorer eye sight/smaller screen devices/lower resolutions to see what the value is.

The advantage of the current display is that the text appearance shows a more detailed display of the battery level whilst the icon can give a quicker visual display. The added colour when running low on power also allows for a quick indication regardless of visual worries mentioned above.

Comment: But the displays are becoming more advanced and of higher resolution. So I don't think there will be a problem in fitting the text in the icon. Should be clear

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard -  ᵗʰᵉʳᵉ ʷⁱˡˡ ˢᵗⁱˡˡ ᵇᵉ ᵖᵉᵒᵖˡᵉ ᵗʰᵃᵗ ˢᵗʳᵘᵍᵍˡᵉ ᵇᵉᶜᵃᵘˢᵉ ᵒᶠ ᵖᵒᵒʳᵉʳ ᵉʸᵉˢⁱᵍʰᵗ ᵒʳ ᵉᵛᵉⁿ ᵗʰᵒˢᵉ ᵗʰᵃᵗ ʲᵘˢᵗ ʰᵃᵛᵉ ᵖʰᵒⁿᵉˢ ʷⁱᵗʰ ˢᵐᵃˡˡᵉʳ ˢᶜʳᵉᵉⁿˢ

Comment: I really like the way you presented it. Since the design also has the change of color to indicate the health of the problem I guess that should help them.

Comment: @Siva-Dev-Wizard - That doesn't help those that are colour-blind all that much though :) (another reason the display shows both)

Comment: You think to the extremes Sayse. :)